# Passing data between forms and saving it in a txt file

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm trying to send/pass the data from form1 to form2 so form2 can save it in a txt file.
The info is being written in a textbox, saved in bool.

I've tried 'public static string *SetValueforName* = ""; and then later in the code *SetValueforName* = *NameBox.Text*; but on form2 I wrote *Form1.SetValueforName* to save it in a text file 9after hitting a button) but it didn't work... (I used StreamWriter)

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: First question: why do you want it written to a text file? But besides that, post the code you currently have, what you expected, what you've tried, where the error is etc - also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please add your code, so we can tell what is wrong with it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.